# repaint() doesn't invoke paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I'm trying to make a pong game in Java but it doesn't work. 
I've done some testing and it seems that the variables are updating but that when I do 
`repaint();` in the timers `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` doesn't call the `paintComponent()` method

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PongGame extends JComponent implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener{

    public int state = 1;
    public int paddleX;
    public String buttonColor = "blue";
    public int mouseX, mouseY;
    private int ballX = 400;
    private int ballY = 150;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Pong");
        PongGame game = new PongGame();
        window.add(new PongGame());
        window.pack();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);

        Timer t = new Timer(20, game);
        t.start();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        paddleX = mouseX;

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0, 800, 600);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.fillRect(paddleX, 550, 150, 15);
        g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 30, 30);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ballX = ballX + 10;
        ballY = ballY + 10;
        System.out.println(ballX + " " + ballY);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX = e.getX();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- you haven't registered the implemented `MouseMotionListener` to any component:

  ```
  game.addMouseMotionListener(game);
  ```
- you are not adding your first created instance of `PongGame` to the frame rather added a new one producing bug:

  ```
   PongGame game = new PongGame();
    window.add(new PongGame());  // <<--- why creating the new instance ?
                // it should be window.add(game);
  ```
- As a good programming practice: try putting the add listener code in the component's own creating context i.e., in their constructor to make your code better readable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
PongGame game = new PongGame();
window.add(new PongGame());
```

You have two instances of `PongGame`. One added to the frame (`new PongGame()`) and the other (`game`) that actually reacts to the timer. Change this row to:

```
window.add(game);
```

Answer (score 1):

To correct the actual problem.  Add a constructor (tested locally):

```
PongGame() {
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

Comment: But as noted by others, `PongGame game = new PongGame();` is entirely redundant.

Comment: I would like you to review my giff program before public sharing about which i told you. Would you give me your opinion ?

Comment: *"I would like you to review my giff program.."*  If you are after OO design advice, I am the wrong person to ask.  Did you mean just 'generally'?  If so, you can reach me through andrewthommo at gmail.

Comment: That is fine ;) Thank you. I will send you it in 1-2 days.

Answer (score 0):

repaint() does not invoke paint() directly. It schedules a call to an intermediate method, update(). Finally, update() calls paint() (unless you override update).

The reason for this complexity is Java's support for concurrent programming. It does this using threads.

Using repaint() can be tricky for at least three reasons.

1. the interaction between repaint() and the spontaneous painting done by the GUI thread
2. the fact that repaint() just asks the thread system to schedule a call to update()/paint() and then exits. The repaint() method is asynchronous.
3. the problem of preventing your drawing from being erased when being updated.

I suggest you to try the same with update().

Useful link : http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/~mes/courses/cps530/programs/threads/Repaint/index.html

Comment: Your advice is good for AWT but is not appropriate for Swing where `update()` should not be called unless it is being called to update the Look & Feel.

Comment: Also:  [Review the edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20573439/revisions) to see how to make an 'ordered list'.  Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: For more details, please see Oracle's article, [Painting with Swing and AWT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to see why they state `"... for this reason update() is never invoked on Swing components..."`.